# Which statistical methods could I use to determine if a price is good, based on a history of prices?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, computational-statistics

I have the following scenario:

- A history of prices of a specific product;
- The current price of the same product.

The history of prices should contain prices with a certain amount of discount, very low prices (black friday prices) and "normal" retail prices.

Based on the history of prices, I want to determine if the current price is good for buying the product. The current price might not be the lowest price of the history, but still be a good price.

I have a very simple algorithm to do it:

- I have a minimum ammount of discount per product, say 15%
- Based on the history, I have an average price (`sum(prices) / sum(quantity)`)
- If the current price is 15% (or the configured minimum discount) lower than the average price, it is a good price for buying.

This is very simple, but it does not always work.

The history of prices could contain older products with several months of data, or newer products with a few weeks of price data. It is acceptable that the final algorithm will work better for older products with more data.

Which statistical methods could I apply that would make the algorithm more precise?

Comment: Under what circumstances does your current algorithm not work?

Comment: Inflation adjusted prices?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the historical prices are since the past is over.  The only way that the past matters is in predicting future prices, so it only matters if you're comparing buying now versus buying later.  If you're just asking whether you should buy now, all that matters is the value to you compared with the price.  History does not matter.

Comment: Bill the Lizard: It does not work when the history of prices has only higher prices. When a "not so high" price shows up, it detects as a good price for buying, but it's not (when examined by a human).

Comment: Economics teaches us that whether a price is "good" depends on more than the history of past prices.  What are *your* specific criteria for determining the amount of "goodness" of any particular price?

Comment: I am talking about final consumer goods, like a TV, a phone, a refrigerator, etc.. So, a good price means the human perception of a good price. Say you are looking for a TV and it usually costs around $1100.00 and $1200.00. Suddently you see if for $999. By your perception, it's probably a good price. In general, it's more about the human perception than economics.

Comment: First. I totally agree with @whuber's point. Second. It might be an idea to look at the kinds of trading rules that are used in finance (specifically, technical analysis) for buying or selling stocks. They can be complex, but you could try to establish rules based on a variety of moving averages and local or global trends. If you have some "fundamental value" in mind, I'm sure you could introduce into that the trading rule, too. Sorry I cannot provide a specific example. How many products and how much automation is required will be important considerations.

Comment: @ThiagoSayão Not sure if this is within the scope of your problem, but maybe you can improve your algorithm by determining not only if the price is good (relative to historical values) but also determining if the product is a better buy for the customer. This gives you more flexibility (e.g. looking at competing products, look at previous reviews, etc) in order to provide better info to the people using your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Build a good ARIMA model for your price history incorporating memory, events (e.g. Black Friday etc ...), day-of-the-week, seasonal dummies, level shifts , local time trends and the run a program that incorporates robust ARIMA (not AIC or BIC based as those procedures assume no outliers and restrict the model form to a list) and assess whether or not an intervention pulse has occurred at the last period. If it has then an exception has been detected ... if not then nothing exceptional in last data point.

To do science is to search for repeated  patterns.
To detect anomalies is to identify values that do not follow repeated patterns.

For whoever knows the ways of Nature will more easily notice her deviations
and, on the other hand, whoever knows her deviations will more accurately
describe her ways.

One learns the rules by observing when the current rules fail.

The problem is that you can't catch an outlier without a model (at least a mild one) for your data. Else how would you know that a point violated that model? In fact, the process of growing understanding and finding and examining outliers must be iterative. This isn't a new thought. Bacon, writing in Novum Organum about 400 years ago said:

"errors of Nature, sports and monsters correct the understanding in regard to ordinary things, and reveal general forms. For whoever knows the ways of Nature will more easily notice her deviations; and, on the other hand, whoever knows her deviations will more accurately describe her ways." [ II 29]

Comment: Why would a model to predict the current price from previous prices have any relationship to a determination that the current price is "good"?

Comment: "good ARIMA model" had nothing to do with current price. The current price can be evaluated by assessing the probability of it being observed before it was observed. That is the alpha value of the identified pulse at the last period. I didn't comment about the current price being good other than saying that if an intervention is detected at the last price, it might cause one to be suspect about the last price arising due to chance.

Comment: I interpreted the "good" to mean is the current price consistent with expectations.If it is inconsistent with expectations then it would be classifies as "ungood"

Comment: That latter comment is helpful in showing how your answer is related to the question. But I would suggest that you refine your characterization of "good," because I suspect most people would believe that a price inconsistent with expectations--but *subtantially lower* than them--is a "good one."  (I won't comment on whether such a belief is correct, except to point out that in some markets the appearance of an unexpectedly low price might signal important changes that cause careful consumers to delay their purchases.)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the answer depends on the dynamics of the prices, so having a model for that would be required, as a previous answer indicates. It seems to me that if one cannot assume anything about prices, this would be related to the secretary (or princess....) problem.

If all, say $r$, suitors of a princess are summoned sequentially to her presence and she is able to rank them, the strategy that maximizes her chance of choosing the optimal candidate is to reject the first $\approx r/e$ and then pick the first one which dominates all the previously seen, in case there is one (otherwise, put up with the last one): see Billingsley, *Probability Theory*, for instance.

However, this is a strategy that maximizes her chances of getting the very best suitor, a more conservative princess might prefer a strategy that produces a good enough partner. Seeing all prices in sequence and acting likewise might give you the maximum chance to get the lowest one, but perhaps at the cost of missing quite often prices which are nearly as good.

Just a thought, probably irrelevant but which may give you some idea.